# Thank you, Geoff

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team, thanks

It seems that after 11 years, Geoff Dalgas - "[Valued Associate #00003](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/21/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00003/)" - [has decided to hang up his hat as a developer at Stack Exchange](https://twitter.com/SuperDalgas/status/1294348068054335489).

That deserves... Some recognition and gratitude!

### Let's talk about Geoff, baby

Eleven years. *Eleven (**11**)* years! Twelve, if you count all the work he was doing with Jeff and Jarrod before becoming an "official" employee. [User #2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas) - here from day -1, from a tiny team without so much as an office to the juggernaut we see today... That's a heck of a run. And ol' Geoff has had a heck of an impact here. Look to your left. Now look to your right. Now look back at your computer, where this site is displayed. Chances are, Geoff's work is responsible in part for *everything* you see in that browser window. From handling physical hardware in the first data center, to crafting the review system that allows each post on these sites to be vetted by cyborgs before slapping humans in their soft fleshy eyeballs... From creating new sites from elemental SQL to infusing all who work with him with a renewed sense of wonder and excitement for the boundless possibilities that lie ahead... from enhancing the editing system to beefing up the commercial versions of this software which are sold for the vast amounts of cash which pay for *everything else...* The depth and range of Geoff's work here has been astounding.

Geoff embodies those aspects which I consider the soul of Stack Overflow: boundless curiosity, technical acumen, an irrepressible willingness to help, playful good humor, guiding practicality, and governing humility. He is quick to offer assistance, and quick to seek feedback. He persistently eschewed empty self-promotion, preferring to demonstrate by example both what was possible and what was desirable in both words and deeds.

From his fortress in the great Pacific Northwest, Geoff has reached out and improved all of our lives, with such grace and care that most of us barely even knew it. And yet, we would all be far worse off were it not for his efforts.

### The bat-signal beckons

Now Geoff is leaving. But this is not a time for sadness, nor maudlin remembrance. Where Geoff goes, it must be certain that he is needed - so let us put aside selfish thoughts and rejoice in that knowledge.

Join me then, won't you, in bidding Geoff fond farewell, and thanking him heartily for his efforts over these past many years!

Comment: You had me at "Hello" Geoff.

Comment: If only I could +500...    T_T

Comment: @fasterthanlight you can give a +100 bounty.

Comment: Where is the "Thank you" button when we need 'em? ;-)

Comment: Gosh, Geoff was originally a Visual Basic programmer, Respect.

Comment: Is it just my non-account ... but the link to twitter in the question is broken?

Comment: @user1271772 You can't award bounties to questions, only to answers.

Comment: Sad that it took an ex-employee to post this. Recognition and gratitude indeed!

Comment: He is the OG "Geoff Dalgas". Thank you for creating this community!

Comment: Good luck and continued success.

Answer (score 416, accepted):

Dangit Shog9! I was doing ok holding it together until I read this - now someone is chopping onions everywhere I go!

I wanted to take a moment and say that it really has been my honor and privilege to be part of the mission to bring Stack to life but I'm really just a small part in the great community that has formed around the bits that are flowing on your screen.  Every feature request, all the good ideas, and some of the bad have all come together to make Stack what it is today. There is also an awesome team that works tirelessly behind the scenes every single day trying to make good things happen. All of the work they do is for the love of the mission - to help others learn something new, share a nugget of knowledge, or bask in the amazing talents of others. I have learned so much from all of you and will always be a Stacker no matter what happens. Know that I leave Stack in awesome hands with a team who really has their act together. The work they do won't always be perfect, but with your help it's going to get just a bit better every single day. I'll be cheering from the sidelines as one of Stacks biggest fans!

Comment: I would be very happy to see you more active around here, and on any SE site. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you man, thank you for everything which made this site a good one.

Comment: Apparently I'm supposed to check if you're ok with us featuring this. I hope so, since I feel its pretty much the least we can do for someone who's contributed so much to the community.  I'm a little grumpy over the peer who is making a fuss over this, but they kinda have the right of it in terms of what the rules say. So, could I have your permission to feature this?

Comment: Apparent permission granted. :)

Comment: Taking a break, or jumping right back in elsewhere? Anyway, good luck and all the best Geoff; hard to believe it's been all these years now.

Comment: I love that your top tag is [Status-Completed].  Thanks for all the good stuff you got done.

Comment: Best wishes, Geoff! Nice to see the dev team getting some love on meta.

Answer (score 48):

Thank you Geoff, for everything.

I can't even dream to surpass Shog's words, so I won't try. I'll just say that I admire your work, both as a programmer and as an ordinary user who sees the end result, and am happy for you for taking a new path.

And as for Stack Exchange, I really hope for its sake that you gave good lessons​ to whoever arrived to replace you. That person has got big shoes to fill. :-)

Comment: Whatever he does, we know that he will not be camping! Right Dalgas?

Comment: I'll be back soon, Shadow :)

Comment: @Ollie beware the monkeys! :-D

Answer (score 25):

(Shog9 has barely left any room for more praises.)

I've only just come across this post and have already got to know a good deal on how great the work was of our #1 (Valued Associate #3 actually, but whatever).

I have only been a member of the Stack Exchange community (*[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)*) for around seven months now, but I should owe all that I learnt back there, over this period of time, to all the developers who brought the Stack Network to life.

Thank you, Geoff!

Comment: We all do, we all owe him!

Answer (score 23):

Thank you very much for your work, Geoff!

You were one of those who provided such a great place for seeking and finding help for thousands (if not millions) of us.

Hope you stay along to contribute some ideas as well as experience of yours in the future, to make Stack Exchange even better.

Have a big party. You deserve it.

Answer (score 16):

**Thank you, Geoff Dalgas.**

Geoff, I am raising a cup of tea to you, as it's a little early for a glass of champagne  even for me.  Please, y'all, let's have a ten-minute round of ringing applause for Geoff Dalgas!

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Big thanks to shog9 and Geoff. Especially from the perspective of a user who came in "much" later: it is always refreshing, and positive to learn about the long history of this community.

And about the positive people who made this happen, and who did their part to shape an awesome experience.

Beyond that, it is really helpful to hear

> The work they do won't always be perfect, but with your help it's going to get just a bit better every single day.

... as that helps bringing back trust. When shog9 (and countless others) trust Geoff, then Geoff trusts *the team*, then that boosts my trust in *that team* quite a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks, Geoff. I did not know him before, but now that I have read about him, I believe he deserves more than thank you, but that's all I can do currently.

So once again, thank you! And I'm happy to join you in this, Shog9. :-)

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I don't get it either. I got those from reputable Senior Stack Overflow members with multiple thousand rep. I get why it needs to be edited. But, I don't see why they have to down vote it. Anyway what i wrote is just expression of what I felt. They may down vote the post, but it is not gonna make any difference on gratitude i have in my heart.

Comment: Ah, I see you are a man/woman of culture as well

Comment: The other reason i could think of is some times people see down voted thing and then BOOM they believe that it has to be down voted you know like mob mentality.

Comment: Do you mind seeing my only post and point out one offensive or wrong thing, it has -15 score

Comment: @BabaYaga yeah I did. and it's amazing the answer have a lot of up vote while the question is running down. But don't evaluate yourself with the votes. Sometimes votes show the attitude the person asking the question and sometimes they show the attitude of the person voting. So just ignore and keep on expressing your thoughts.

Comment: I am in bad terms with some users, anyway we can get together in [this](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1508/general-chatroom). I am currently chat suspended, my suspension ends in about 12hr. Looking forward to have a good exchange of thoughts

Comment: @Ollie they have voted to delete my written expressed gratitude. you can see the list here https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/353154/revisions and, Of-course votes are anonymous.

Comment: I have been a member of MSE for seven years. I upvoted Shog9's post. I appreciate that Geoff is a cornerstone of SO, and yet, I swear, this is the first time I have ever heard of him or seen his avatar. I did not post saying "thank you" because 1. I never heard of him until Shog's post. 2. Shog's post does a better job of thanking Geoff for his service 3. There are already several posts thanking Geoff. 4. I don't need easy rep :)

Comment: A possible explanation for the downvotes *could* be: All or some of the above.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I totally agree with you on the first comment. People are grateful for the things they have never seen or things they have never experienced the result of, like it happens in most of religion no offense. At least I am being benefited from this platform which happens to be sweat and hard work of Geoff and other SO founders as well  as developers. If people are grateful for things that are doing nothing, would it hurt anybody if i took a moment to say Thank you to the people who did real a good job? Nope!

Comment: So why bother voting? Are you suggesting that it's somehow better and more productive to post another "thank you" piece? Yours is the sixth.  In any case, I didn't DV, I tried to explain why your post has not been received as positively as you expected.